# WIX create user and use him to give permissions to folder

Tags: wix, custom-action

I need to create installer which creates new local user, new folder and gives full permissions to this user.

I created small test below using new wix project via Visual Studio 2010 and Wix 3.10:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="DG" UpgradeCode="85e3204f-c872-4229-bb75-fa5231863a75">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>

    <Feature Id='TestUserProductFeature' Title='Test User Product Feature' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='TestUserProductComponent' />
    </Feature>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='ConfigureUsers' Before='CreateFolders'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>

  <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Component Id='TestUserProductComponent' Guid='652C2BE1-9DE7-47AD-A686-55ABAAF68B6F'>
        <util:User Id='TEST_USER1' Name='testName1' Password='pa$$$$word' CreateUser='yes' FailIfExists='yes'/>
      </Component>
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" >
          <Directory Id="d_TestDirectory" Name="TestDirectory">
            <Component Id="CreateTestDirectory" Guid="8B7EB548-5767-7017-A56C-4EEBDDF7B621">
              <CreateFolder Directory="d_TestDirectory">
                <Permission User="testName1" GenericAll="yes" />
              </CreateFolder>
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
        </Directory>    
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">           
      <ComponentRef Id="CreateTestDirectory"/>     
        </ComponentGroup>    
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Please note I added

```
<Custom Action='ConfigureUsers' Before='CreateFolders'/>
```

To create user before creating of new folder.
Also please note I added

```
FailIfExists='yes'
```

for util:User so it will fail if user exists.

When I run my msi with logging, I get this message first:
An error occured while applying security settings. testName1 is not a vaild user or group. This could be a problem with the package, or a problem connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check your network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install.

This means that my user was not created.
Then I create local user myself manually and press Retry.

Then I get this error:
Failed  to create user (-2147022672 testName1 )
It means that installer cannot create user because it's already created(FailIfExists='yes')

This is my InstallExecuteSequence from Orca:
FindRelatedProducts     25
LaunchConditions        100
ValidateProductID       700
CostInitialize      800
FileCost        900
CostFinalize        1000
MigrateFeatureStates        1200
InstallValidate     1400
RemoveExistingProducts      1401
InstallInitialize       1500
ProcessComponents       1600
UnpublishFeatures       1800
RemoveFolders       3600
ConfigureUsers      3699
CreateFolders       3700
RegisterUser        6000
RegisterProduct     6100
PublishFeatures     6300
PublishProduct      6400
InstallFinalize     6600

This is a part of my log file with actions logging:

```
Action start 0:02:47: RemoveFolders.
Action ended 0:02:47: RemoveFolders. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:02:47:389]: Doing action: ConfigureUsers
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:02:47:389]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:02:47: ConfigureUsers.
MSI (s) (D8:28) [00:02:47:391]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIDFFA.tmp, Entrypoint: ConfigureUsers
MSI (s) (D8:48) [00:02:47:391]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (D8:48) [00:02:47:392]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 1440 (0x5A0).
MSI (s) (D8:E4) [00:02:47:409]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (D8:E4) [00:02:47:410]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
MSI (s) (D8!30) [00:02:47:475]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CreateUserRollback property. Its value is '**********'.
MSI (s) (D8!30) [00:02:47:476]: Doing action: CreateUserRollback
MSI (s) (D8!30) [00:02:47:476]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:02:47: CreateUserRollback.
Action ended 0:02:47: CreateUserRollback. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8!30) [00:02:47:477]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CreateUser property. Its value is '**********'.
MSI (s) (D8!30) [00:02:47:478]: Doing action: CreateUser
MSI (s) (D8!30) [00:02:47:478]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:02:47: CreateUser.
Action ended 0:02:47: CreateUser. Return value 1.
Action ended 0:02:47: ConfigureUsers. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:02:47:481]: Doing action: CreateFolders
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:02:47:481]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:02:47: CreateFolders.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:02:47:481]: Note: 1: 1609 2: testName1 3: 1332 
MSI (c) (B4:B8) [00:02:47:483]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

Error 1609. An error occurred while applying security settings. testName1 is not a valid user or group. This could be a problem with the package, or a problem connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check your network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install. Unable to locate the user's SID, system error 1332
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:14:513]: 
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:14:513]: Note: 1: 1609 2: testName1 3: 1332 
MSI (c) (B4:B8) [00:03:14:515]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

Error 1609. An error occurred while applying security settings. testName1 is not a valid user or group. This could be a problem with the package, or a problem connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check your network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install. Unable to locate the user's SID, system error 1332
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:485]: 
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:486]: Finished allocating new user SID
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:486]: Using well known SID for System
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:486]: Finished allocating new user SID
Action ended 0:03:31: CreateFolders. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:486]: Doing action: RegisterUser
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:486]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:03:31: RegisterUser.
Action ended 0:03:31: RegisterUser. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:487]: Doing action: RegisterProduct
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:487]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:03:31: RegisterProduct.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:487]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:488]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductToBeRegistered property. Its value is '1'.
Action ended 0:03:31: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:488]: Doing action: PublishFeatures
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:488]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:03:31: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 0:03:31: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:489]: Doing action: PublishProduct
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:489]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:03:31: PublishProduct.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:490]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Icon 
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:490]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Icon 4: SELECT `Name`, `Data` FROM `Icon` 
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:490]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Media 3: -2147287038 
Action ended 0:03:31: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:490]: Doing action: InstallFinalize
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:490]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 0:03:31: InstallFinalize.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:491]: Running Script: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIDFE9.tmp
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:491]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UpdateStarted property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:491]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:493]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:494]: Executing op: Header(Signature=1397708873,Version=500,Timestamp=1216610392,LangId=1033,Platform=0,ScriptType=1,ScriptMajorVersion=21,ScriptMinorVersion=4,ScriptAttributes=1)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:494]: Executing op: ProductInfo(ProductKey={718267EA-D291-4ED2-8BA6-F3B872BEA874},ProductName=SetupProject1,PackageName=SetupProject1.msi,Language=1033,Version=16777216,Assignment=1,ObsoleteArg=0,,,PackageCode={413012CF-A56C-4342-9DE3-50774CA5DD67},,,InstanceType=0,LUASetting=0,RemoteURTInstalls=0,ProductDeploymentFlags=2)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:494]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=0,Argument=1033)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:494]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=1,Argument=SetupProject1)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:495]: Executing op: RollbackInfo(,RollbackAction=Rollback,RollbackDescription=Rolling back action:,RollbackTemplate=[1],CleanupAction=RollbackCleanup,CleanupDescription=Removing backup files,CleanupTemplate=File: [1])
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:495]: Executing op: SetBaseline(Baseline=0,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:495]: Executing op: SetBaseline(Baseline=1,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:495]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ProcessComponents,Description=Updating component registration,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:495]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=2,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=24000)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:495]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={652C2BE1-9DE7-47AD-A686-55ABAAF68B6F},KeyPath=C:\,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:496]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={8B7EB548-5767-7017-A56C-4EEBDDF7B621},KeyPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\SetupProject1\TestDirectory\,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:496]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CreateUserRollback,,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:496]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=CreateUserRollback,ActionType=11521,Source=BinaryData,Target=**********,CustomActionData=**********)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:497]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CreateUser,,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:03:31:497]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=CreateUser,ActionType=11265,Source=BinaryData,Target=**********,CustomActionData=**********)
MSI (s) (D8:64) [00:03:31:498]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8C49.tmp, Entrypoint: CreateUser
MSI (s) (D8:48) [00:03:31:498]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (D8:48) [00:03:31:499]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 2476 (0x9AC).
MSI (s) (D8:E4) [00:03:31:517]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (D8:E4) [00:03:31:517]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
CreateUser:  Error 0x800708b0: failed to create user: testName1
MSI (c) (B4:B8) [00:03:31:600]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

Error 26401. Failed to create user.  (-2147022672   testName1      )
MSI (s) (D8!58) [00:04:07:562]: Product: SetupProject1 -- Error 26401. Failed to create user.  (-2147022672   testName1      )

CustomAction CreateUser returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 0:04:07: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:566]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:566]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:567]: Executing op: Header(Signature=1397708873,Version=500,Timestamp=1216610416,LangId=1033,Platform=0,ScriptType=2,ScriptMajorVersion=21,ScriptMinorVersion=4,ScriptAttributes=1)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:567]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=0,Argument=1033)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:567]: Executing op: DialogInfo(Type=1,Argument=SetupProject1)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:568]: Executing op: RollbackInfo(,RollbackAction=Rollback,RollbackDescription=Rolling back action:,RollbackTemplate=[1],CleanupAction=RollbackCleanup,CleanupDescription=Removing backup files,CleanupTemplate=File: [1])
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:569]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CreateUser,,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:569]: Executing op: ProductInfo(ProductKey={718267EA-D291-4ED2-8BA6-F3B872BEA874},ProductName=SetupProject1,PackageName=SetupProject1.msi,Language=1033,Version=16777216,Assignment=1,ObsoleteArg=0,,,PackageCode={413012CF-A56C-4342-9DE3-50774CA5DD67},,,InstanceType=0,LUASetting=0,RemoteURTInstalls=0,ProductDeploymentFlags=2)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:569]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CreateUserRollback,,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:569]: Executing op: CustomActionRollback(Action=CreateUserRollback,ActionType=11521,Source=BinaryData,Target=**********,CustomActionData=**********)
MSI (s) (D8:C8) [00:04:07:571]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1929.tmp, Entrypoint: RemoveUser
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:950]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ProcessComponents,Description=Updating component registration,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:950]: Executing op: ComponentUnregister(ComponentId={8B7EB548-5767-7017-A56C-4EEBDDF7B621},ProductKey={718267EA-D291-4ED2-8BA6-F3B872BEA874},BinaryType=0,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:950]: Executing op: ComponentUnregister(ComponentId={652C2BE1-9DE7-47AD-A686-55ABAAF68B6F},ProductKey={718267EA-D291-4ED2-8BA6-F3B872BEA874},BinaryType=0,)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:950]: Executing op: End(Checksum=0,ProgressTotalHDWord=0,ProgressTotalLDWord=0)
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:950]: Error in rollback skipped.  Return: 5
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:953]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:953]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 13, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 38, szDescription: "".
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:954]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:07:954]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (D8:88) [00:04:08:135]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 0:04:08: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

So, it seems like CreateUser is actually run as elevated (deffered) custom action from another temp dll during InstallFinalize action.
Even if ConfigureUsers is said to run before CreateFolders, it just plans elevated custom action.

Is my scenario possible to be achieved? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're doing with immediate custom actions - they are never supposed to alter the system because there is no way to undo them. All custom actions that alter the system need to be deferred so that they a) Roll back with a rollback CA and b) run elevated because immediate CAs are not elevated. If some CAs depend on others just order them appropriately.

That CreateUser error 0x8007089a means "The specified username is invalid.". If that trace code that shows "vmtest\user" is correct, maybe that's incorrect. Why the backslash? Is the "user" part a password? Also I don't believe that the trace would reveal a password, so maybe the user name is "vmtest\user" and that backslash is invalid as part of a user name.

Comment: I created small test, reproducing the issue. It is creating user avoiding backslash and attempts to create folder with full permissions for that user.
Seems like I cannot achieve this order of actions: 1. create user 2 use him to grant permissions on new folder because create user action is planned to run later as elevated, that's how I understand that by the moment

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE**: This isn't an answer to the exact problem above, but may help guide someone to the correct answer.*

Invalid username and/or password may be the cause of the following errors.

```
CreateUser: Error 0x8007089a: failed to create user: JohnSmith
Error 26401. Failed to create user. (-2147022694 JohnSmith
```

Non-alphanumeric characters in the username or password may be the cause, even those these characters are valid for a password. This might be a bug in the Wix Toolset v3.